# Inserting column range in vba

Tags: vba

I have a report in which I have to insert a new column between the last and second to last columns. However, when I try to insert the the column, I get a type mismatch error.

```
Dim columnInsert As Range
Dim rangeAverage As Range

Set columnInsert = Range("X80:X95")
Set rangeAverage = Range("AA1")

Columns(columnInsert:rangeAverage).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

The problem pointed out by the editor is this line:

`Columns(columnInsert:rangeAverage).Insert Shift:=xlToRight`

Basically all I want to do is insert 15 long blank column between AA1 and Z, but I keep running into problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The range you entered in your `.Insert` statement is incorrect

`Columns(columnInsert:rangeAverage)` translates to `Columns(Range("X80:X95"):Range("AA1"))`

---

This will shift only the cells in the range specified:

```
columnInsert.Insert Shift:=xlToRight    'shifts only the cells from X80:X95 to right
rangeAverage.Insert Shift:=xlToRight    'shifts cell AA1 to right
```

This will shift the entire column AA to the right

```
Columns(rangeAverage).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns(rangeAverage.Column).Insert Shift:=xlToRight
```

---

Any of the statements bellow insert a blank column between Column Z and AA:

```
Columns("AA:AA").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns("AA").Insert Shift:=xlToRight
Columns(27).Insert Shift:=xlToRight         'column index
```

---

You can also insert multiple columns:

```
Columns("Z:AA").Insert Shift:=xlToLeft
```

This inserts 2 empty columns to between column Y and Z

Comment: Ahhh I see, that makes much more sense. Thanks paul!

Comment: I'm glad it helped. You should also start qualifying your ranges with the worksheet you intend to update, so if you work on Sheet1 and somehow Sheet2 will become active your changes will apply the Sheet2 instead of the intended Sheet1. You can prefix the statements like this `Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns(27).Insert Shift:=xlToRight`

Comment: Ok, so I am now trying to refer to a named range for column AA, but when I try to set it to a variable I keep getting a type mismatch. Is there a way I can post the code here? I'm new to stackOverflow, I'm not sure if this is how things are supposed to be done :(

Comment: If the initial issue is fixed it would be better to accept the answer then open a new question for the next issue with more details about the named range and the code